# Modify Realm Object from background thread cannot update on main thread immeditly

Tags: multithreading, background, realm

Modify Realm Object from background thread cannot update on main thread immeditly
My code is like this:

```
class demo: NSObject {

    var mail: OutMailModel?
    func demotest() {
        let realm = try! Realm()
        let mailID = 10001
        self.mail = realm.object(ofType: OutMailModel.self,forPrimaryKey: mailID)
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            let realm = try! Realm()
            if let myMail = realm.object(ofType: OutMailModel.self,forPrimaryKey: mailID) {
                try! realm.write {
                    myMail.message = "xxxx"
                }
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                NSLog("mail.message:\(self.mail?.message)") // message not change 
            }
        }

    }
}
```

event this not work:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    if let myMail = realm.object(ofType: OutMailModel.self,forPrimaryKey: mailID) {
        NSLog("mail.message:\(myMail.message)") // message not changed
    }
}
```

what's wrong is the code? Any one help?

Answer (score 3):

When updating the realm from a background thread, the changes might not be visible because the realm isn't being updated with the new information. From the [docs](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#seeing-changes-from-other-threads):

> On the main UI thread (or any thread with a runloop) objects will
>   automatically update with changes from other threads between each
>   iteration of the runloop. At any other time you will be working on the
>   snapshot, so individual methods always see a consistent view and never
>   have to worry about what happens on other threads.

You can call `realm.refresh()` to force a refresh of the realm:

```
func demotest() {
    ...

    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        let realm = try! Realm()
        if let myMail = realm.object(ofType: OutMailModel.self,forPrimaryKey: mailID) {
            try! realm.write {
                myMail.message = "xxxx"
            }
        }

        realm.refresh();

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            NSLog("mail.message:\(self.mail?.message)") // message not change 
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You should have told him to use `notificationToken` and Realm Notifications instead to be notified of when the change has occurred.

Comment: I will try realm.refresh(). Thanks very much.